# How can I efficiently store nearly-identical, immutable, printable documents?

Tags: pdf

In several web applications I've worked on, we've generated and stored PDFs for things like form letters and invoices.

In each case, there's three elements involved:

- a **generic template** with fields to be filled (like "Dear [customer name],..." and "[item_description]..."). This could be an HTML template, a function, or whatever.
- the **varying text** - customer's name, items and amounts for the invoice, etc
- the **final output** - a complete PDF binary

Although any two letters or invoices probably differ by < 1kb of text, we end up storing a separate, complete PDF blob for each. This is a waste of space, whether in a database or in a filesystem ([an unpleasant choice](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2445/files-in-the-database-or-not)).

I've considered storing just the varying text and the template, and producing the PDF on demand, but 1) producing PDFs was slow and 2) old documents should always reprint the same way, not change because the template has been updated since they were saved.

Is there some solution I'm overlooking? I want to:

- Store a template (maybe with versioning)
- Store some varying text
- Allow the user to print that, now or 5 years from now, and have it look exactly the same (**whether or not it's a PDF is irrelevant**)
- Minimize storage requirements

**How can I efficiently store nearly-identical, immutable, printable documents?**

Comment: 1. Strange, about PDFs on-demand too slow. You are not making them 'from text'? Stamping pre-made light-weight background-less invoices etc. as 'watermark' PDFs onto existing background PDF should not be _too_ slow. 2. PDF can reference external content (`Reference XObjects`) -- but only if files are used, by end user, in controlled environment (Reader (Acrobat) only, its security settings adjusted, it can access templates locally) -- then it's feasible.

Comment: I've seen PDFs generated via `wkhtmltopdf`, via a Ruby library called "Prawn", and via Apache PDFBox (to fill out fillable templates with data), in increasing order of speed. None were blazing fast.

Answer (score 2):

The following discusses a general approach that may work if you can copy, the template, update it incrementally, then save and strip, keeping just the the incremental section of the PDF.

This can be recombined with the original PDF at a later time.

Schematically, an incrementally updated PDF looks like.

[image: Incremental Update]

If you have a one common original template, plus a number of different updates that need to applied to produce different variations then it could make a lot of sense to store the original version once, then save just the incremental portion of the output PDFs. These can be recombined, when needed, by simply appending the updated fragment back onto the original PDF.

The stripping of the incremental portion of the PDF should be easily achieved at a low-level using your preferred programming language.

The basic structure of the intermediate PDF (original PDF + incremental updates) will look like:

```
%PDF-1.3

   %% ** Original document body ****
xref
0 9
0000000000 65535 f 
0000000014 00000 n 
%% ** ...etc **
trailer
<<
  /Root 1 0 R
  /Size 9
>>
startxref
644
%%EOF

  %% ** Updated section ***

xref
0 1
0000000000 65535 f 
3 1
0000000951 00000 n 
9 3
0000000892 00000 n 
0000001024 00000 n 
0000001200 00000 n 
trailer
<<
  % ...
>>
startxref
1324
%%EOF
```

The section up to, and include, the second-to-last `%%EOF` is your original template. This is the invariant portion, which should match the original PDF and only needs to be stored once.

The update section is everything after the second-to-last `%%EOF` in the PDF are they varying text, as incremental updates, that need to be stored multiple times.

Hopefully you can find a suitable tool that does incremental updates and produces final PDFs with only a small update section appended.

See also [How to edit PDF files using Incremental Updates](https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2013/06/how-to-edit-pdf-files/)

Comment: Oh, interesting - I generally think of PDFs as opaque blobs of data.